# POST data to controller with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, post

I am using ASP.NET MVC with C# and pure bootstrap. One of my views contains a label, text input box, and a submit button:

```
@{
   ViewBag.Title = "BinSearch";
   Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutSearch.cshtml";
}

<h2>BinConfig Search</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("FiEdit", "EditConfigController"))
{
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="issuerKey">Issuer Key</label>
        <input type="text" name="key" />
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Search" />
    </div>
}
```

When I click the "submit" button, I would like to transfer the data to a controller, EditConfigController to this method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult FiEdit(int key)
{
    return View(new IssuerKey().Key = key);
}
```

Which then is supposed to create a new view where I can edit data based off the key provided. This is the FiEdit view:

```
@model BinFiClient.Models.IssuerKey

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "FiEdit";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutEdit.cshtml";
}

<h2>FiEdit</h2>
```

However, when I click the "submit" button, I receive a 404 error, and the URL path looks like this:

```
http://localhost:58725/EditConfigController/FiEdit
```

Which is actually the path to the method in the controller that I posted above.

What I need is basically a way to POST data to another controller. How can I accomplish this?

Edit:
Now I am receiving the error:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Int32', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'BinFiClient.Models.IssuerKey'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing your code with the following:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("FiEdit", "EditConfig", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="issuerKey">Issuer Key</label>
        <input type="text" name="key" />
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Search" />
    </div>
}
```

This will POST the parameter `key` to the EditConfig controller.

If you'd like to post to the action TestEdit in another controller, say the TestController, your code should be changed to the following:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("TestEdit", "Test", FormMethod.Post))
...
```

To resolve the "model item passed into the dictionary" error, change your POST to be this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult FiEdit(int key)
{
    return View(new IssuerKey() { Key = key });
}
```

Comment: This seems to have helped, but now I am presented with the error `The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Int32', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'BinFiClient.Models.IssuerKey'.` Why would that be?

Comment: Never mind, figured it out! Looks like I was accidentally passing in an integer to my view instead of the IssuerKey it required. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

ou can try with:

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm(("FiEdit", "EditConfigController", FormMethod.Post,
                new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" })))
{
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="issuerKey">Issuer Key</label>
        <input type="text" name="key" />
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Search" />
    </div>
}
```

Comment: @TobyCaulk ups! was an error, but now the code is fixed.

Comment: Try with: 
`public ActionResult FiEdit()
    {
var key = Request.Params["key"].ToString();
        return View(new IssuerKey().Key = key);
    }` The problem looks like how the data is sent to the controller.
In the page isn't defined any model to get in your view and send it to the controller again.