# Get data of HTML Form used in view in ASP.NET Core 6 MVC

Tags: forms, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-6.0

I'm new to ASP.NET Core MVC, so please bear with me if this question seems dumb. I have made an HTML Form in the view of a ASP.NET Core 6 MVC application and I want that when I click on the "Submit" button of the form then the form data is stored in an object. And I can use that object to print the form data that is submitted by the user.

How can I do that?

HTML Form in view markup:

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}

<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>HTML 5 Boilerplate</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>

      <div class="Complaint_Form">

          <h1 class="complaint_heading">
              <span>Complaints</span>
          </h1>

          <div class="entry-content">
            
            <h4>Complaint Lodgement Form</h4>
            <p>Your complaint will be inquired by our Service Standard and Quality – 
                Complaint Management Division. Depending upon the nature of the complaint, 
                we will respond to you at the earliest possible.
            </p>

          </div>

          <h1 class="complaint_heading">
              <span>User Details</span>
          </h1>

          <form method="post">

          <!--Checking if customer's account exist or not-->
          <div class="customer_checking">
              <label for="customer_check" style="font-weight: 500;">Allied Bank Customer*</label>
              
              <input type="radio" id="yes" name="customer_check" value="Yes">
                <label for="Yes">Yes</label>
              
                <input type="radio" id="no" name="customer_check" value="No">
              <label for="no">No</label>
          </div>

          <div class="form-row">

              <!--Customer's Full Name-->
              <div class="individual_form">
                  <label for="fullname" style="font-weight: 500;">Full Name<span style="color: rgb(185, 74, 72);">*</span></label>
                  <input type="text" id="fullname" name="fullname" required>
              </div>

              <!--Customer's CNIC-->
              <div class="individual_form">
                  <label for="cnic" style="font-weight: 500;">CNIC/SNIC<span style="color: rgb(185, 74, 72);">*</span></label>
                  <input type="text" id="cnic" name="cnic" required>
              </div>

          </div>
          
          <div class="form-row">

              <!--Customer's area of concern-->
              <div class="individual_form">

                  <label for="concerned_area" style="font-weight: 500;">Please select the area of concern<span style="color: rgb(185, 74, 72);">*</span></label>

                    <select id="concerned_area" name="concerned_area" style="width: 300px;" required>
                      <option selected="true" disabled="disabled"></option>    
                      <option value="Branch Banking Services">Branch Banking Services</option>
                      <option value="Debit/Credit/Prepaid Card">Debit/Credit/Prepaid Card</option>
                      <option value="My ABL Internet / Mobile Banking">My ABL Internet / Mobile Banking</option>
                      <option value="Phone Banking Services">Phone Banking Services</option>
                      <option value="Loan / Trade Products ">Loan / Trade Products</option>
                      <option value="Others">Others</option>
                    </select>

                </div>

              <!--Customer's Complaint-->
              <div class="individual_form">

                  <label id="complaint" style="font-weight: 500;">Complaint Details<span style="color: rgb(185, 74, 72);">*</span></label>
                  <textarea id="complaint_textarea" name="complaint" rows="4" cols="50" required></textarea>

              </div>

          </div>

          <p style="font-weight: bold; color: #707070;">Note: ABL Customers are requested to provide account details in the complaint description above.</p>

          <div class="form-row">

              <!--Incident Date-->
              <div class="individual_form">

                  <label for="incident_date" style="font-weight: 500;">Date of Incident<span style="color: rgb(185, 74, 72);">*</span></label>
                  <input type="date" id="incident_date" name="incident_date" required>

              </div>

              <!--Name of the branch-->
              <div class="individual_form">

                  <label for="branch_name" style="font-weight: 500;">Branch Name</label>
                  <input type="text" id="branch_name" name="branch_name">

              </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-row">

              <!--Medium through which the customer should be contacted-->
              <div class="individual_form">

                  <label for="preferred_communication_medium" style="font-weight: 500;">Please select the preferred medium for communication<span style="color: rgb(185, 74, 72);">*</span></label>
                  
                  <div class="check_div">

                      <input type="radio" id="Call_Back" name="preferred_communication_medium" value="Call Back" required>
                      <label for="Call Back">Call Back</label>

                  </div>

                  <div class="check_div">

                      <input type="radio" id="Email" name="preferred_communication_medium" value="Email" required>
                      <label for="Email">Email</label>

                  </div>
              </div>

              <!--Time to contact customer-->
              <div class="individual_form_Check">

                  <label id="preferred_call_time" style="font-weight: 500;">Please select the preferred time to call you<span style="color: rgb(185, 74, 72);">*</span></label>
                  
                  <div class="check_div">
                      
                      <input type="checkbox" id="Morning" name="preferred_call_time" value="Morning" required>
                      <label for="Morning">Morning</label>

                  </div>

                  <div class="check_div">
                      
                      <input type="checkbox" id="Afternoon" name="preferred_call_time" value="Afternoon" required>
                      <label for="Afternoon">Afternoon</label>

                  </div>

                  <div class="check_div">

                      
                      <input type="checkbox" id="Evening" name="preferred_call_time" value="Evening" required>
                      <label for="Evening">Evening</label>

                  </div>

              </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-row">


              <!--Customer's contact number-->
              <div class="individual_form">

                  <label for="cuntomer_number" style="font-weight: 500;">Contact Number<span style="color: rgb(185, 74, 72);">*</span></label>
                  <input type="text" id="cuntomer_number" name="customer_number" required>

              </div>

              <!--Customer's Email Address-->
              <div class="individual_form">

                  <label for="email_address" style="font-weight: 500;">Email Address<span style="color: rgb(185, 74, 72);">**</span></label>
                  <input type="text" id="email_address" name="email_address" required>

              </div>
          </div>

          <p style="color: rgb(102, 102, 102); font-size: 14px; font-weight: 400px;"><em>*indicates mandatory fields.<br>
          ** indicates mandatory field in case communication preference is email.</em></p>

          <input style="background: #072b5d !important;border-color: #14365f !important;color: #fff !important;border: 0;padding: 10px 30px;" type="submit" value="Submit"/>

        </form>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Start off with a simple example and then extend it to include all your Form inputs https://stackoverflow.com/q/30514140/495455

Comment: "Submit" button of the form then the form data is stored in an object. Do you mean you want to use Model to store the form data ?

Answer (score 0):

> "Submit" button of the form then the form data is stored in an object.

Below is demo to create the model, and pass the data to the controller. You can refer to it.

In Home Privacy action code is like below, form is in Privacy view.

```
        public IActionResult Privacy()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Privacy(User user)
        {               
            return View();
        }
```

User model

```
public class User
{
        public string customer_check { get; set; }
        public string fullname { get; set; }
        public string cnic { get; set; }
        public string concerned_area { get; set; }
        public string complaint { get; set; }    
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime  incident_date { get; set; }
        public string branch_name { get; set; }
        public string preferred_communication_medium { get; set; }    
        public List<string> preferred_call_time { get; set; }
        public string customer_number { get; set; }
        public string email_address { get; set; }
}
```

Result:

[image]